# Correct way to present an ActionSheet with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, swiftui

I want to show ActionSheet (or any other modal, but Alert) on some event like button tap.

I found the way of doing it using the state variable. It seems a little bit strange for me to display it that way because I have to reset variable when ActionSheet closes manually.

Is there a better way to do it?

Why there is a separate method for presenting Alert that allows you to bind its visibility to a state variable? What's the difference with my approach?

```swift
struct Sketch : View {
    @State var showActionSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: { showActionSheet = true }) { Text("Show") }
        }
        .presentation(showActionSheet ?
            ActionSheet(
                title: Text("Action"),
                buttons: [
                    ActionSheet.Button.cancel() { 
                        self. showActionSheet = false 
                    }
                ]) 
        : nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enforcing the preference for the state variable approach, Apple has adopted for the alert and action sheet APIs. For the benefit of others who find this question, here are updated examples of all 3 types based on Xcode 11 beta 7, iOS 13.

```
@State var showAlert = false
@State var showActionSheet = false
@State var showAddModal = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // ALERT
        Button(action: { self.showAlert = true }) {
            Text("Show Alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
             // Alert(...)
             // showAlert set to false through the binding
        }

        // ACTION SHEET
        Button(action: { self.showActionSheet = true }) {
            Text("Show Action Sheet")
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
             // ActionSheet(...)
             // showActionSheet set to false through the binding
        }

        // FULL-SCREEN VIEW
        Button(action: { self.showAddModal = true }) {
            Text("Show Modal")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddModal, onDismiss: {} ) {
            // INSERT a call to the new view, and in it set showAddModal = false to close
            // e.g. AddItem(isPresented: self.$showAddModal)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the modal part of your question, you could use a `PresentationButton`:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        PresentationButton(Text("Click to show"), destination: DetailView())
    }
}
```

[Source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-new-view-using-presentationbutton)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Sketch : View {
    @State var showActionSheet = false

    var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Button(action: { self.showActionSheet.toggle() }) { Text("Show") }
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Test"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would work, a @State is a property wrapper and your action sheet will keep an eye on it, whenever it turns to true, the action sheet will be shown

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best way to show multiple action sheets according to requirements.

```
struct ActionSheetBootCamp: View {

@State private var isShowingActionSheet = false
@State private var sheetType: SheetTypes = .isOtherPost

enum SheetTypes {
    case isMyPost
    case isOtherPost
}

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Button("Other Post") {
            sheetType = .isOtherPost
            isShowingActionSheet.toggle()
        }
        Button("My post") {
            sheetType = .isMyPost
            isShowingActionSheet.toggle()
        }
    }.actionSheet(isPresented: $isShowingActionSheet, content: getActionSheet)
}

func getActionSheet() -> ActionSheet {
    
    let btn_share: ActionSheet.Button = .default(Text("Share")) {
        //Implementation
    }
    let btn_report: ActionSheet.Button = .destructive(Text("Report")) {
        //Implementation
    }
    let btn_edit: ActionSheet.Button = .default(Text("Edit")) {
        //Implementation
    }
    let btn_cancel: ActionSheet.Button = .cancel()
    switch(sheetType) {
    case .isMyPost:
        return ActionSheet(title: Text("This is the action sheet title"), message: nil, buttons: [btn_share,btn_edit, btn_cancel])
    case .isOtherPost:
        return ActionSheet(title: Text("This is the action sheet title"), message: nil, buttons: [btn_share,btn_report, btn_cancel])
    }
    
}
}
```